# `caption` bug (?) where `\captionsetup[figure]` within a figure has no effect

Tags: captions

I am trying to change a caption format with the `caption` package within a float environment (in this case `figure`). However, `\captionsetup[figure]{}` is not working within the `\begin{figure} ... \end{figure}` which is definitely possible and described on [pg. 4 of the `caption` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption), namely:

> It’s good to know that \captionsetup has an effect on the current
> environment only. So if you want to change settings for the current
> figure or table only, just place the `\captionsetup` command inside the
> figure or table right before the \caption command. For example
> `\begin{figure}` . . . `\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=off}` `\caption{. . .}` `\end{figure}` switches the single-line-check off, but only for this
> figure, so all the other captions remain untouched.

I cannot recall having issues with this before, can anybody reproduce this issue or provide guidance on how to fix it so the local `\captionsetup` is used? I think I am calling the commands correctly although a simple error on my end is likely too.

The log file (with `\showfiles`):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty)
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file test.aux.

Caption Info: Option list on `figure'
Caption Data: {position=bottom,labelfont={Large,it}, labelsep=period} on input 
line 27.


Package caption Warning: Unused \captionsetup[figure] on input line 25.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

[1{c:/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)

 *File List*
    book.cls    2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
    bk10.clo    2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 caption.sty    2022/03/01 v3.6b Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2022/03/17 v2.3b caption3 kernel (AR)
  keyval.sty    2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
subcaption.sty    2022/01/07 v1.5 Sub-captions (AR)
l3backend-pdftex.def    2023-01-16 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
 ***********

 )<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx9.pfb><c:/texl
ive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><c:/texlive/2022/t
exmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 30235 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,labelfont={bf, small}, textfont={small}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
\caption{Bold and small}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\captionsetup[figure]{position=bottom,labelfont={Large,it}, labelsep=period}
\caption{Large and italic}
\showcaptionsetup{figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

How it currently looks:

[image]

Comment: Quite curiously, the warning disappears if another `figure` follows, but the caption style doesn't change.

Comment: @egreg When I remove the `[figure]` then the code compiles but in my main document, I have `\captionsetup[subfigure]` which meant I wanted to not affect `subcaptions` too by changing a local definition "global" when I `\input` other files. Just requires careful management but it is not mentioned in the documentation not to use it within a float, I am not sure why it won't work though it is puzzling.

Comment: How about reporting your problem to the maintainer of the package?

Comment: @PeterWilson I will do that now on GitLab, was just checking that this wasn't me making a mistake or if it was already a known "bug" to the frequenters here.

Comment: Thank you. It's a long time since I had anything to do with any packages I might have produced. My intellectual capabilities have faded, but not as fast as my memory. Don't trust me.   --- Peter W.  --- GOM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per @Peter Wilson's comment, I contacted the `caption` maintainer on their [issue tracker on GitLab here](https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/159) and I appreciate the maintainer responding so quickly with:

> Options given via `\captionsetup[x]{...}` will be applied at the
> beginning of the environment `x` (and not at the `\caption` within the
> environment x), and therefore the `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` is "too
> late" to be applied because `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` adds the given
> options to the "list of options applied at the beginning of the figure
> environment" only. It was implemented this way because otherwise
> something like `\captionsetup{...}` within a figure would not overwrite
> options given with `\captionsetup[figure]{...}` at the preamble, and
> otherwise it would make the order of utilization of options to
> sub-captions even more complicated.

The maintainer has said that they will update the `caption` documentation in a new release to make it clearer that `\captionsetup["float"]{...}` is applied at the beginning of the environment and is not suitable to be used within a "float" environment. I was unaware of this after going through the `caption` documentation pdf so maybe this will help others who might face the same issue prior to its release.

Comment: \captionsetup inside figure changes the figure caption localy, not the subfigure caption nor future figures.